# I have a table with 2 colums, with select/input[type=date] elements in the same row, they conflict and mess up the style of the entire table

Tags: html, css

http://prntscr.com/8qa833 Ive spent well over 4-5 hours trying different methods... But this isn't my only issue, I cant get the input[type=date] element to change, the width 100% doesn't seem to affect it when changing screen sizes. If I can't find a solution I'll have to just give in and make it a fixed size.

HTML

```
<center>
<div id="signup-form" style="/*display:none;*/">
    <form method="post">
        <table width="30%" align="center" border="0" style="max-width:570px;">

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username" required="" id="username" pattern=".{4,25}" title="Username must be 4-25 characters long" maxlength="25" oninput="usernamecheck()">
                        <p id="usernameerror" class="error"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="" id="email" oninput="emailcheck()" class="failed">
                        <p id="emailerror" class="error">This is not a valid email.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required="" id="password" pattern=".{6,50}" title="Password must be 6-50 characters long" maxlength="50" oninput="passwordcheck()" class="failed">
                        <p id="passworderror" class="error">Password must be atleast 6 characters!</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required="" id="firstname">
                        <p id="firstnameerror" class="error"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required="" id="lastname">
                        <p id="lastnameerror" class="error"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select id="country" name="country" required="" title="Please Select a Country.">
                            <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Country</option>
                            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                            <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
                            <option value="AL">Albania</option>
                            <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                            <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                            <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
                            <option value="AO">Angola</option>
                            <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
                            <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
                            <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                            <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
                            <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
                            <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
                            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
                            <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
                            <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
                            <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
                            <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
                            <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
                            <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
                            <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                            <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
                            <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
                            <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
                            <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
                            <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
                            <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
                            <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                            <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
                            <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
                            <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
                            <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                            <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                            <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
                            <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
                            <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
                            <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
                            <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
                            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                            <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
                            <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
                            <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
                            <option value="TD">Chad</option>
                            <option value="CL">Chile</option>
                            <option value="CN">China</option>
                            <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
                            <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
                            <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
                            <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
                            <option value="CG">Congo</option>
                            <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
                            <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
                            <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
                            <option value="CI">Côte dIvoire</option>
                            <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
                            <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
                            <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
                            <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
                            <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
                            <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
                            <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
                            <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
                            <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
                            <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
                            <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
                            <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
                            <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                            <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
                            <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
                            <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
                            <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                            <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
                            <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
                            <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                            <option value="FR">France</option>
                            <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
                            <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
                            <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
                            <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
                            <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
                            <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                            <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
                            <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
                            <option value="GR">Greece</option>
                            <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
                            <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
                            <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
                            <option value="GU">Guam</option>
                            <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
                            <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
                            <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
                            <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                            <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
                            <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
                            <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
                            <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
                            <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
                            <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
                            <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
                            <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
                            <option value="IN">India</option>
                            <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
                            <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
                            <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
                            <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
                            <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
                            <option value="IL">Israel</option>
                            <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                            <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
                            <option value="JP">Japan</option>
                            <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
                            <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
                            <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
                            <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
                            <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
                            <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic Peoples Republic of</option>
                            <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
                            <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
                            <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                            <option value="LA">Lao Peoples Democratic Republic</option>
                            <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
                            <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
                            <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
                            <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
                            <option value="LY">Libya</option>
                            <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
                            <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
                            <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
                            <option value="MO">Macao</option>
                            <option value="MK">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
                            <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
                            <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
                            <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
                            <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
                            <option value="ML">Mali</option>
                            <option value="MT">Malta</option>
                            <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
                            <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
                            <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
                            <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
                            <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
                            <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
                            <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
                            <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
                            <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
                            <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
                            <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
                            <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
                            <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
                            <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
                            <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
                            <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
                            <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
                            <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
                            <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
                            <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                            <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
                            <option value="NE">Niger</option>
                            <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
                            <option value="NU">Niue</option>
                            <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
                            <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                            <option value="NO">Norway</option>
                            <option value="OM">Oman</option>
                            <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
                            <option value="PW">Palau</option>
                            <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
                            <option value="PA">Panama</option>
                            <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
                            <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
                            <option value="PE">Peru</option>
                            <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
                            <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
                            <option value="PL">Poland</option>
                            <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
                            <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                            <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
                            <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
                            <option value="RO">Romania</option>
                            <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
                            <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
                            <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
                            <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
                            <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                            <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
                            <option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
                            <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                            <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                            <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
                            <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
                            <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                            <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
                            <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
                            <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
                            <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
                            <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
                            <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
                            <option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
                            <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
                            <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
                            <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
                            <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
                            <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
                            <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
                            <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
                            <option value="ES">Spain</option>
                            <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
                            <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
                            <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
                            <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
                            <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
                            <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
                            <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
                            <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                            <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
                            <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
                            <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
                            <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
                            <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
                            <option value="TG">Togo</option>
                            <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
                            <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
                            <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                            <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
                            <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
                            <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
                            <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                            <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
                            <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
                            <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
                            <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
                            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                            <option value="US">United States</option>
                            <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                            <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
                            <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
                            <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
                            <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
                            <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
                            <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
                            <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
                            <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                            <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
                            <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
                            <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
                            <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
                        </select>
                        <p id="countryerror" class="error"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" name="age" placeholder="Age" required="" id="age" pattern="" value="" title="You must be 18 years of age or older." oninput="agecheck()">
                        <p id="ageerror" class="error"></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <button type="submit" name="btn-signup" id="confirmsignup">Sign Me Up</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</center>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
CSS Document * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#login-form {
margin-top: 70px;
}
table {
border: solid #dcdcdc 1px;
padding: 25px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
table tr,td {
padding: 10px;//
border: solid #e1e1e1 1px;
}
table tr td input {
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
border: solid #e1e1e1 1px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
background: #f9f9f9;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
table tr td button {
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
border: 0px;
background: rgba(12, 45, 78, 11);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #595959, #515151);
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.2);
color: #f9f9f9;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bolder;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
table tr td button:active {
position: relative;
top: 1px;
}
table tr td a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00a2d1;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}
/* css for home page  */

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background: rgba(00, 11, 22, 33);
color: #9fa8b0;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
#header #left {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
#header #left label {
position: relative;
top: 5px;
left: 100px;
font-size: 35px;
}
#header #right {
float: right;
position: relative;
}
#header #right #content {
position: relative;
top: 20px;
right: 100px;
color: #fff;
}
#header #right #content a {
color: #00a2d1;
}
/* css for home page */

#country {
/* width:100%; */
height: 45px;
border: solid #e1e1e1 1px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
background: #f9f9f9;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
max-width: 215px;
margin-right: 25px;
}
#age {
width: 100%;
/* max-width: 203px; */
}
#username {
/* width: 98%; */
}
#email {
/* width: 98%; */
}
#password {
/* width: 98%; */
}
input[type=date] {
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
border: solid #e1e1e1 1px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
background: #f9f9f9;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.error {
color: red!important;
font-family: sans-serif!important;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
top: 15px;
}
button#confirmsignup[disabled] {
background-color: grey;
cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Is there some sort of default style for this element I'm forgetting to overwrite that's completely messing it up?

Comment: Don't layout your page with a table.  Use CSS.

Comment: In the end this table will be implemented into a much large page, plus i was trying to re-use my code from a previous project, however just using CSS on some div elements probably would be best at this point.

Comment: Don't reuse table code on a new project, you'll regret it later.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I missed a default CSS tag for the `<select>` tag box-sizing: border-box; I needed box-sizing:content-box;

Comment: Yay!  Good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is messed up about it, as i do not see an example of 'functioning' and 'incorrect' to compare. Also, it seems that because the elements are set to 100%, and the tr styling alone width is not set, it will only will only be the width of the date control, and so is acting the way it is. May seem stupid, but have you tried to use the important override param like so: width = 100% !important or better to use fixed size, and set max and min width like so:

```
table tr td input {
width: 100% !important;
height: 45px;
border: solid #e1e1e1 1px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding-left: 10px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
background: #f9f9f9;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

The !important property value tells it to ignore any inherited value or priority from inhertinace of other elements or heiarchy. I have found uses for it, but primarily when coming into a project already created, and the desing layout didn't fit to what we needed. Poorly built, or not thought of. Anyways, see if that helps.